# How can i add am option box into my Folium Draw Toolbar?

Tags: django, dictionary, leaflet, google-maps-markers, folium

I'm working on a proyect where i use Folium and plugin.drawn in order to handle markers and polygons,

The idea it is simple, save all markers en polygons created on the map. It is a collaborative map

On the map I have three layers (layer 1: Ubicacion de mujeres, layer 2: Zona de Violencia and layer 3: Poblaciones diversas). What i need is to add markers for any layer the user choose so i would like to add an option box with those layers as options as you can see in the image

[image: my options example]

here it is my map too
[image: current map]

At the moment i'm making a deep research about it. I tried to add macros like this

```
{% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
```

but I don't get to know how to do it correctly

Any idea that you recommend me is going to be so helpful
Thank you guys

PD: I'm new in this